# Let A be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is this a valid proof for $c \geq 0 \Rightarrow \sup(cA)=c\sup(A)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sup(cA) = \alpha$ and $\sup(A) = \beta$. For any $\epsilon_1>0$, $\alpha - \epsilon_1$ is not an upper bound of $A$, therefore $\exists a_{\epsilon_1} \in A$ s.t. $\alpha - \epsilon_1 < ca_{\epsilon_1}$. Note that $a_{\epsilon_1} \leq \beta$, then $\alpha - \epsilon_1 < ca_1 \leq c\beta$. Hence $\alpha < c\beta + \epsilon_1$ for any $\epsilon_1>0$, which implies that $\alpha \leq c\beta$.

Similarly, for any $\epsilon_2>0$, $\exists b_{\epsilon_2} \in A$ s.t. $\beta-\epsilon_2 < a_{\epsilon_2}$. As $c>0$, therefore $c\beta - c\epsilon_2 < ca_{\epsilon_2} \leq \alpha$.
So $c\beta \leq \alpha + c\epsilon_2$ for any $\epsilon_2>0$ implies $c\beta \leq \alpha$. Together we derive $\alpha = c\beta$.

Comment: Well the statement is false for example if $A=\{0\}$. Also your proof doesn’t exclude this case. Also, your last line when you say it’s a contradiction, it’s actually not.

Comment: $c \sup \{0\} = \sup \{ c \cdot 0 \}$.

Comment: You need to assume that $A$ is a non-empty, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.